# FluentBootstrap - Tab Content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

am busy fiddling with fluent-bootstrap considering a move to the new syntax builder, but I cant reproduce an existing working tab with content in an existing project. Does someone have a complete sample somewhere showing how to navigate their syntax model? I say complete because their samples only show how to generate the 'tablist' portion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly your problem is. Maybe this helps you: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "fluent-bootstrap" library you're referring to? I run FluentBootstrap.com, but I'm guessing that's not what you're talking about since it doesn't implement the JavaScript controls yet (though they are coming soon).

Answer (score 1):

[Fluent doesn't natively support this feature.](https://github.com/daveaglick/FluentBootstrap/issues/40)

I had a similar issue where the Fluent Bootstrap only gave me the tab/pills, and I was after the dynamic content too. Below is the Fluent code that I used in order to product what I was after:-

```
            @Html.Bootstrap().Div().AddCss(Css.PageHeader)
            {
                @Html.Bootstrap().Heading1("Nav - Tabs")
            }

            using (var tabs = Html.Bootstrap().Tabs().Begin())
            {
                @tabs.Tab("Home", "#tabhome").SetActive().AddAttribute("aria-controls", "home").AddAttribute("role", "tab").AddAttribute("data-toggle", "tab")
                @tabs.Tab("Profile", "#tabprofile").AddAttribute("aria-controls", "profile").AddAttribute("role", "tab").AddAttribute("data-toggle", "tab")
                @tabs.Tab("Messages", "#tabmessages").AddAttribute("aria-controls", "messages").AddAttribute("role", "tab").AddAttribute("data-toggle", "tab")
                @tabs.Tab("Settings", "#tabsettings").AddAttribute("aria-controls", "settings").AddAttribute("role", "tab").AddAttribute("data-toggle", "tab")
            }
            using (Html.Bootstrap().Div().AddCss("tab-content").Begin())
            {
                using (Html.Bootstrap().Div().SetId("tabhome").AddCss("tab-pane", "active").AddAttribute("role", "tabpanel").Begin())
                {
                    <h3>Home Content</h3>
                    <text>Here is some tab content relating to the home page.</text>
                    <a class ="btn btn-link" href="https://github.com/daveaglick/FluentBootstrap/issues/40" target="_blank">Tabs not natively supported in Fluent Bootstrap</a>
                }
                using (Html.Bootstrap().Div().SetId("tabprofile").AddCss("tab-pane").AddAttribute("role", "tabpanel").Begin())
                {
                    <h3>Profile Content</h3>
                    <text>Here is some tab content relating to the profile page.</text>
                }
                using (Html.Bootstrap().Div().SetId("tabmessages").AddCss("tab-pane").AddAttribute("role", "tabpanel").Begin())
                {
                    <h3>Messages Content</h3>
                    <text>Here is some tab content relating to the messages page.</text>
                }
                using (Html.Bootstrap().Div().SetId("tabsettings").AddCss("tab-pane").AddAttribute("role", "tabpanel").Begin())
                {
                    <h3>Settings Content</h3>
                    <text>Here is some tab content relating to the settings page.</text>
                }
            }
```

Comment: Also, link to explanation that Fluent doesn't naively support this feature: [link] (https://github.com/daveaglick/FluentBootstrap/issues/40)